# How to get rid of "Unsafe Encryption Error" on PlayStore

Tags: android, security, encryption, md5, android-security

I have uploaded an application on play store which has md5 encryption functions and I have also used jmrtd library for mrz and nfc detection. The play store is repeatedly giving this error. I am not using any hard coded key for md5 encryption. The key is generated by data given by user on login page.
I have tried using different keys for md5 encryption but the error persists. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: Error image here]

> 1 MESSAGE FOR VERSION CODE 18
> Unsafe encryption
> Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details.
> org.jmrtd.protocol.PACEProtocol->pseudoRandomFunction

Comment: The "unsafe encryption" is in the jMRTD / PACE **library**, not in your MD5 function. By the way, MD5 is not encryption, it's a very old hash function.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have already published an app on playstore with jmrtd library in it. But I haven't got any error on that app.

Comment: Have you tried replacing MD5 with SHA-256? Maybe you need to share code just for us to figure out what you mean with MD5 encryption and how you are using a key with MD5...

Comment: The error message clearly indicates that the problematic function is `PACEProtocol->pseudoRandomFunction`. Do you use this method directly or indirect (add a break-point and debug your code if you don't know where it is used)?

Comment: @Robert yes this function is being used inside the jmrtd library. But I am still confused that if this is causing issue then why the other app with same library not causing issue.

Comment: The problem function is inside the library and I cannot edit the library(if we can I don't know how to as I am new to this). So, any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Comment: @MahinMunir are you using "minifyEnabled true" in the app that fails but not in the other? I have been releasing an app to an Internal Testing track, all went good until I started using obfuscation and set "minifyEnabled true", these bundles get systematically rejected with the same message, although previous bundles that aren't obfuscated don't show this error.